# JavaScript for preloading images doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Here is my code. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Internet Explorer and also it doesn't work in Mobile Safari.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.correct4').load(function () {
        $("#gallery .loader4").css("display", "none");
        $("#gallery .correct4").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*? Check F12 for any console messages. You might also consider the Network tab to ensure that the images are located, and loaded.

Comment: What does this code have to do with preloading images?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It could be that he's using the means of background-image to preload images, or perhaps the images are loaded in these elements as image tags. Not really sure.

Comment: We need more info in order to help you.  What exactly is "not working"?  How exactly are you preloading images?

Comment: my css is: #gallery .correct4 {display:none} my goal is to first load the image and when it is loaded display it. While it is loading It should display loader4 (animated gif file) When the large image loaded loader4 should stop displaying and instead it should display loaded image

Comment: Like others have stated, your question is lacking.  However, I have noticed that if images are hidden, IE will fire the `load()` event as if the hidden images don't exist.

Comment: @Sparky672: `fire the load() event as if the hidden images don't exist`.  I'm confused, does that mean the event will be fired or not?

Comment: @Rocket: What I've noticed is that IE will fire the `load()` event even if/when the hidden images are not yet loaded.

Comment: @Sparky672 I think you are right because all my ie shows is loading image without never showing loaded image

Comment: I mean it shows .gif file and doesn't want to switch to .jpg

Comment: @Sparky Is there anything I can do if that's the case?

Comment: Mine was part of a complex plugin.  I simply put my images inside a hidden container `div` instead of hiding the images themselves.  This worked for me.  Then once the assets loaded, the `.load()` fired and revealed the container with images already inside.

Comment: @Sparky That's perfect!!! Thank you so much That should work!

Comment: I've turned it into an answer.  Please "accept" it if it solves your problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that IE will fire the jQuery `.load()` [event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) even if/when the *hidden* images are not yet loaded.  It's like it completely ignores hidden images when deciding to fire the `.load()` event.

To get around this, I simply put my images inside a hidden container `div` instead of hiding the images themselves.  Then once the contained assets fully load, the `.load()` event will fire and reveal the container with the images already inside.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="containerDiv">
    <img src="/image.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
    <img src="/picture.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#containerDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('img').load(function() {
    $('#containerDiv').css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would stay away from the jQuery load event... You dont really want to load anything into the DOM at this point. You just want to make reference of all the images you want to have in cache. I normally approach it like this. On document ready create an empty array, add a new Image object for each image to the array, then assign the 'src' property to the image, and then every image you created in the array will be in your cache. This will work across all browsers... Its been tested.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

imagesSearchPage = new Array();

imagesSearchPage ["imageTitle01"] = new Image();
imagesSearchPage ["imageTitle01"].src = "images/imageTitle01.png";
imagesSearchPage ["imageTitle02"] = new Image();
imagesSearchPage ["imageTitle02"].src = "images/imageTitle02.png";
imagesSearchPage ["imageTitle03"] = new Image();
imagesSearchPage ["imageTitle03"].src = "images/imageTitle03.png";
});
```

I usually create a new array for each page just to keep things organized. I know it might seem like a lot of code but all your images will be cached and you can also reference the image from the array if you need to.

Clear your cache, open up your dev tools, click on Network > Images, and you will see the images.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are confused... the OP is talking about [the jQuery `.load()` **event**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).  He was **not** talking about [the jQuery `.load()` **method**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)... two completely different things.

Comment: Ok... I see now. Based on the jQuery docs, the load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. I wasn't aware of that. Regardless of that, my example does show how to successfully pre-cache images. So you still deem my answer as not useful Sparky?

Comment: SO answers must be totally relevant to the question, not just useful in some way.  They also must be technically accurate... your answer confuses the load event with the load method.